# I am trying to load another page at same location using "add tab" method in Javascript using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to link another HTML page saved in the same folder as this via jquery. I am also trying to add a tab and load that page in the tab.

I am new to Jquery and I am trying to learn how to work with it.

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Installing and using jQuery Plugins</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"/>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="script17.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

  <h1 id="title">Installing and using jQuery Plugins</h1>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#tabs-1'>Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tabs-2'>Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tabs-3'>Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tabs-1'>
    <p>Junk Text1</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tabs-2'>
    <p>Junk Text2.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tabs-3'>
    <p>Junk Text3</p>
    
  </div>
</div>

<button id='add-tab'>Add tab</button>

  <p><a href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> Check out the themes on this page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
$("#tabs").tabs(); 

  $("#add-tab").click(function(){
  var num_tabs = $("#tabs ul li").length+1;
  $("#tabs ul").append(
     "<li><a href="+"'C9JS_16.html'"+">Click a Quote</a></li>");
  $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
  });

});
```

The file `C9JS_16.html` is saved in the same folder the HTML file.
I am still getting the CORS error in my script.

> C9JS_17.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'file:///E:/Javascript/C9_JS_Fundamentals/C9JS_16.html' from origin
> 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
> supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge,
> https. jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2 GET
> file:///E:/Javascript/C9_JS_Fundamentals/C9JS_16.html net::ERR_FAILED

​

Comment: [How CORS works](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

Comment: Hey Thanks!! But I am too new to Javascript to understand this. Is there s tutorial for beginners? With very simple examples.

Comment: This is a very simple example ;) If you are a beginner its a good point to start, or you can search online tutorials